# Mysql query modification for best Performance

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I am using a Round() function in MySQL query to get a SUM() value with 3 precision. But I am not sure whether this is the best way or get an actual value and round it off in java or js.
I am a bit confused about which is the best practice and why?

`Select ROUND(SUM(ORDER_VALUE),3) from Orders`

or

```
   Select SUM(ORDER_VALUE) from Orders  group by STOCK_ID:

after that 

   DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
   System.out.println(formatter.format(25.0));
```

Comment: Do you need in rounded value for further processing the data received from MySQL on the java side? Round in MySQL query. Or this data will be displayed only? Format (not round!) in displaying control properties, or, if displayed without any control, in Java code.

Comment: in both cases any performance changes?

Comment: No difference in performance. One rounding per rowset? Its overhead is exteremely less than measurement accuracy - no chance to detect.

Comment: thanks a lot, not like rounding per rowset, used a group by, so for example round will be applied to 100 rows in 2000 row data set

Comment: If your rowset produces 100 rows then ROUND() will be applied 200 times - both in MySQL and in Java. And believe - MySQL will do it more effectively, because values processing is its business. Tiny rounding function in MySQL against additional object creation with almost the same rounding function in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know whether it's better to do your rounding to three decimal digits inside MySQL or in your application program.

As long as the SQL statement contains `SUM(ORDER_VALUE)`, It Doesn't Matter, at least as far as the accuracy goes. Before rounding, the `SUM()` operation uses the precision of the column it operates on.

And, the performance difference between your choices is far too small to measure. Far less than a microsecond.

Therefore, it's a matter of making your code as **clear**, and as **easy to reason about**, as it possibly can be. You're dealing with other peoples' money, and you want to be able to convince yourself you've done it right.

When a future customer asks what happened to the fourth and fifth digits of precision, you want to give a short and correct answer.

Is it easier for you, and your future self a year from now, and your co-workers, to read the ROUND in SQL or the string-formatting stuff in Java?

I favor putting the **business rules in one place** in the code. The SQL `SUM` is a business rule, so the `ROUND` should go with it.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT SUM(ROUND(ORDER_VALUE,3)) FROM Orders
```

Comment: Was - one rounding for the entire dataset. Became - one rounding for each row of the dataset.

Comment: AND the resulting value is likely to be better.  Which value does the business logic demand?